# Create JSON with Square brackets instead of curly brackets

Tags: php, json

Tunnelvision:

I have a pretty basic array like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["locations"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["identifier"]=>
    string(4) "0815"
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "ACTIVE"
    ["street"]=>
    string(12) "Mainstreet"
  }
}
```

What I need is a simple output in `JSON` in object-form like this:

```
{ 
   "locations":[ 
      { 
         "identifier":0815,
         "status":"ACTIVE",
         "street":"Mainstreet"
      }
   ]
}
```

I simply can't get it formatted correctly. I tried `json_encode` with the 2nd, optional parameter `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` like this:

```
var_dump(json_encode($patchObjectArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

I tried wrapping it around another array, but also without success. I always end up with having this structure:

```
{ 
   "locations":{ 
      "identifier":"0815",
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "street":"Mainstreet"
   }
}
```

I also tried to parse it into an object with `(object)$patchObjectArray`, also didn't work.

Wrapped another array around it like this: 
`array(array("locations" => $patchObjectArray))`, that just led to another "0"-index, also with curly brackets

What am i missing here?

Comment: __Array of arrays__ is what you need.

Comment: You can't get that output because it's not the same as your data structure.

Comment: The square brackets produce a list/array.

The curly brackets produce an object with key/value pairs.

The list can then be a value of a key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the data structure that will give you the required output:

```
echo json_encode([
    "locations" => [
        [
            "identifier" => "0815",
            "status" => "ACTIVE",
            "street" => "Mainstreet"
        ]
    ]
]);
```

As you can see - your `"locations"` must be **array of arrays**.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $a = ['locations' => [[
                'identifier' => '0815',
                'status' => 'Active',
                'street' => 'Mainstreet'
            ]]];

            echo json_encode($a);
```